# How to design methods which are related to two or more class objects?

Tags: c++, oop

Say I have two classes A and B, I have a method called test which is related to objects from A and B.

I faced a problem in class design, should I put test method in just one class A or B (seems missing the method if I use another)

or should I put the test in both classes A and B(seems redundant)

```
A::test(B b)
B::test(A a)
```

Is there any better way? use non-member function?

Also, I may have methods which are to do with three/four classes, how to handle?

Comment: Make it a standalone function? Or put it in a `Base` class then derive `A` and `B` from `Base`? I recommend to read Items 22 and 23 from Effective C++ (Scott Meyers). It deals exactly with this situation.

Comment: Maybe have it in a base class? Inheritance was created for reuse after all.

Comment: Or let class A subclass B?

Comment: A and B are not derived from the same base

Comment: @AdamLee They could be, with multiple inheritance.

Comment: @AdamLee It's tough to say with no extra information, but if it `test` doesn't naturally belong to either `A` or `B`, it makes sense to implement it as a non-member function.

Comment: @keyser inheritance is not for reuse.

Comment: Without any code example, can't you template `test` to work for each class?

Comment: @райтфолд Wikipedia and I disagree.

Comment: @keyser then you're both wrong.

Comment: @keyser Just ignore him.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you make it a non-member function in the same namespace as `A` and `B`:

```
void test(A a, B b);
```